# JsGrid - Keep sorted order on refresh

Tags: sorting, jsgrid

I have a grid in jsGrid that refreshes every 5 seconds. While filtering is fine and it remains on refresh, sorting the tables does not. Once the refresh hits the table automatically goes back to its unsorted, default, order.

Is there any way to get the JsGrid to keep its sorting on refresh?

Here's my code:

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
  height: "300px",
  width: "100%",
  filtering: true,
  sorting: true,
  paging: true,
  autoload: true,
  pageSize: 10,

  controller: {
    loadData: function(filter) {
      var data = $.Deferred();

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: BASE_URL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
           //SUCCESS MESSAGE
        },
        error: function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
          //ERROR MESSAGE
        }
      }).then(function(result) {
        result = $.grep(result,
          function(item) {
            return //FILTERED RESULTS;
          });

        data.resolve(result);
      });

      return data.promise();
    }
  },

  //SAMPLE FIELDS
  fields: [{
      name: "Name",
      type: "text",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      name: "Age",
      type: "number",
      width: 50
    },
    {
      name: "Address",
      type: "text",
      width: 200
    },
    {
      name: "Country",
      type: "select",
    }
  ]
});

setInterval(function() {
  //Refreshes grid only after 5 seconds
  $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("loadData");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer! A thread was posted yesterday onto GitHub for someone looking for the same thing I was:

[Source](https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/1091)

The answer was inside my `setInterval` function to call the `.done` function and call the jsGrid sorter in there. :

```
setInterval(function() {
  //Refreshes grid only after 5 seconds

     $('#jsGrid').jsGrid("loadData").done(function () {
            var sorting = $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("getSorting");
            $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("sort", sorting);

}, 5000);
```

Comment: For other newbs coming here instead of the jsGrid docs, if the sort field and order is known, you can avoid retrieving the sort and just `$("#jsGrid").jsGrid("sort", 0, 'asc');` (to sort on the first field for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
Below logic of sorting on the basis of number

    $("#Grid2").jsGrid({
        height: "auto",
        width: "100%",
    
        filtering: false,
        editing: false,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        autoload: true,
        inserting: false,
        pageSize: 15,
        pageButtonCount: 5,
    
        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
                var d = $.Deferred();
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "http://" + servername + ":" + portnumber + "/api,
                    data: filter,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        filteredData = $.grep(data, function(item) {
                            //filtering logic
                            ;
                        });
                        d.resolve(filteredData);
                        testdata = JSON.stringify(data);
                        $("#Grid2").jsGrid("sort", 1);
                        HistoricData = data;
                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        console.log(e.responseText);
                        var errorMsg = e.responseText;
                        var msg = errorMsg + " for this particular combination";
                        showError(msg);
                        $("#displayingHistoryValues").hide();
                        $("#ExportGrid2").hide();
                        $("#Grid2").hide();
                        d.resolve();
                    }
                });
    
                return d.promise();
            }
        },
        fields: [{
            title: "Value",
            name: "MeasureValue",
            type: "number",
            width: "5%",
            css: "custom-field",
            sorting: true,
            itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
    
                if (item.MeasureValue != null && item.MeasureValue != '' && item.MeasureValue.trim().length > 0) {
                    var mesval = FormatValeur(item.MeasureUnit, item.MeasureValue);
                    return "<div>" + mesval + "</div>";
                }
    
            }
        }, {
            type: "control",
            editButton: false,
            deleteButton: false,
            width: "5%"
        }]
    })
    

Another way to sort, get the filteredData or loaded  data 
and call onRefresing of JSGrid .

Way to sort JS grid on column after grid load :

onRefreshing: function (args) {
            fundCodeList = [];
            jsonNumLst = [];
            jsonNANLst = [];
            if(this._visibleFieldIndex(this._sortField) == -1 
                    || this._visibleFieldIndex(this._sortField)==1){

                $.each(filteredData, function(inx, obj) {
                    if($.isNumeric(obj.fundCode)){
                        jsonNumLst.push(obj);
                    }else{
                        jsonNANLst.push(obj);
                    }

                });

                if(this._sortOrder == undefined || this._sortOrder == 'asc'){
                    jsonNumLst.sort(sortByNumFCAsc);
                    jsonNANLst.sort(sortByNANFCAsc);
                }else if(this._sortOrder == 'desc'){
                    jsonNANLst.sort(sortByNANFCDesc);
                    jsonNumLst.sort(sortByNumFCDesc);                      
                }

                if(jsonNumLst.length>0 || jsonNANLst.length>0){
                    filteredData = [];
                    if(this._sortOrder == undefined || this._sortOrder == 'asc'){
                        $.each(jsonNumLst, function(inx, obj) {
                            filteredData.push(obj);
                        });
                        if(filteredData.length == jsonNumLst.length){
                            $.each(jsonNANLst, function(inx, obj) {
                                filteredData.push(obj);
                            });
                        }
                    }else if(this._sortOrder == 'desc'){
                        $.each(jsonNANLst, function(inx, obj) {
                            filteredData.push(obj);
                        });

                        if(filteredData.length == jsonNANLst.length){
                            $.each(jsonNumLst, function(inx, obj) {
                                filteredData.push(obj);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                if((filteredData.length>0) && filteredData.length==(jsonNumLst.length+jsonNANLst.length)){
                    $("#measureImportGrid3").data("JSGrid").data = filteredData;
                    //isSortGrid = false;
                    //saveEffectControlData = $('#saveEffectiveControlGrid').jsGrid('option', 'data');
                }
            }


//Ascending order numeric
function sortByNumFCAsc(x,y) {
    return x.fundCode - y.fundCode; 
}

//Ascending order nonnumeric
function sortByNANFCAsc(x,y) {
    return ((x.fundCode == y.fundCode) ? 0 : ((x.fundCode > y.fundCode) ? 1 : -1 ));
}

//Descending order numeric
function sortByNANFCDesc(x,y) {
    return ((x.fundCode == y.fundCode) ? 0 : ((y.fundCode > x.fundCode) ? 1 : -1 ));
}

//Descending order non-numeric
function sortByNumFCDesc(x,y) {
    return y.fundCode - x.fundCode; 
}

        }
```